No able to upgrade storybook to 8.2.4
I am not able to upgrade the storybook to 8.2.4.
After upgrading storybook and run yarn storybook I keep having this issue(see Issue). I have removed the modules folders and I have updated my dev dependencies. I cleared the cache, but I still keep having the same issue of the storybook breaking when it builds when it is trying to find folder assets that do not exist inside the core folder for the storybook. I added my JSON package and storybook configuration to see if there is something missing. Thank you for the help
Issue
Error: Failed to load static files, no such directory: ./node_modules/@storybook/core/assets/browser Make sure this directory exists.     at parseStaticDir (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/presets/common-preset.cjs:133488:11)     at async ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/presets/common-preset.cjs:134265:56     at async Promise.all (index 0)     at async Object.favicon (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/presets/common-preset.cjs:134259:14)     at async useStatics (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:254430:58)     at async Promise.all (index 2)     at async storybookDevServer (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:255771:82)     at async buildOrThrow (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:255340:12)     at async buildDevStandalone (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:256984:79)     at async withTelemetry (./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/core-server/index.cjs:255691:12)

My dependencies
{
  "name": "console",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006 --ci",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "chromatic": "chromatic",
    "license-checker": "node license-checker.js",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.10.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "core-js": "^3.37.0",
    "cron-parser": "^4.9.0",
    "cronstrue": "^2.50.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.11",
    "evergreen-ui": "^7.1.5",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.45",
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "postcss": ">=8.4.31",
    "posthog-js": "^1.130.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-is": "^18.3.1",
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.0",
    "semver": "^7.5.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^4.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^4.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "chromatic": "^11.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.0.0",
    "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
    "storybook": "^8.2.4",
    "storybook-addon-apollo-client": "^7.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "braces": ">=3.0.3",
    "ws": ">=8.17.1"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"
}

Main and Preview for Storubook config
import { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
    "../pages/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "storybook-addon-apollo-client",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook"
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {},
  staticDirs: ["../public"],
  core: {
    disableTelemetry: true,
  },
};
export default config;

import { MockedProvider } from "@apollo/client/testing";
import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router-context.shared-runtime";
import { MockedPremiumProvider } from "../contexts/MockedPremiumContext"; // Ensure this path is correct
import React from "react";

export const decorators = [
  (Story, { parameters }) => {
    // Extract custom parameters for the PremiumProvider
    const { initialPremium, initialPrincipal } =
      parameters?.premiumContext || {};

    return (
      <MockedPremiumProvider
        initialPremium={initialPremium}
        initialPrincipal={initialPrincipal}
      >
        <Story />
      </MockedPremiumProvider>
    );
  },
];

export const parameters = {
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  apolloClient: {
    MockedProvider,
  },
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
  },
};
export const tags = ["autodocs"];

I tried all of these cmds
yarn upgrade-interactive  

rm -rf node_modules                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
yarn cache clean
yarn install

yarn add @storybook/react @storybook/addon-essentials @storybook/addon-links storybook-addon-apollo-client @storybook/nextjs    

yarn add @storybook/react @storybook/addon-essentials @storybook/addon-links storybook-addon-apollo-client @storybook/nextjs --dev    

npx storybook@latest dev -p 6006                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

npx storybook upgrade   


Is the folder that it says is missing there when you navigate to it in your command line  or file explorer?

@scotthecke please read the ticket the folder does not exist, as I mentioned, and is a module folder
